# GestureDetector is not working with Dismissible Widget

Tags: flutter, gesturedetector, dismissible

I am trying to get the **drag offsets** while using **Dismissible** widget. So tried to wrap it with **GestureDetector** but its **onHorizontalDragStart** is not working.
 Tried the either way ie by putting GestureDetector as child of Dismissible but then **Dismissible stopped working**.
How to solve this? Thnx...

```
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: items.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    var item = items[index];
    return GestureDetector(
      onHorizontalDragStart: (e) {
        print(e);
      },
      child: Dismissible(
        key: ValueKey(item),
        background: Container(
          color: Colors.teal,
        ),
        child: ListTile(
          title: Text("item $item"),
        ),
        onDismissed: (d) {
          items.remove(item);
        },
      ),
    );
  },
);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Nested Gesture Widgets**

The reason you are having this issue is because both of those widgets receive touch input and when you have two widgets that receive touch input, long story short the child wins that battle. Here is the long story. So both of your inputs from your `Dismissible` and `GestureDetector` are sent to what is called a `GestureArena`. There the arena takes into account multiple different factors but the end of the story is the child always wins. You can fix this issue by defining your own `RawGestureDetector` with its own `GestureFactory` which will change the way the arena performs.

```
ListView.builder(
      physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      itemCount: items.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        var item = items[index];
        return Listener(
          child: Dismissible(
            key: ValueKey(item),
            child: ListTile(
              title: Text('This is some text'),
            ),
            onDismissed: (DismissDirection direction) {
              items.remove(index);
            },
          ),
          onPointerMove: (PointerMoveEvent move) {
            if (move.localDelta.dx > 1) {//Ideally this number whould be 
//(move.localDelta.dx != 0) but that is too sensitive so you can play with 
//this number till you find something you like. 
              print(move.position);
            }
          },
        );
      },
    );
```

I want to give all credit to Nash the author of [Flutter Deep Dive: Gestures](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-deep-dive-gestures-c16203b3434f) this is a great article I highly recommend you check it out.

Comment: Thnx dude, let me try and will get back to you.

Comment: bro it was really helpful but still i couldn't find a way to pass gesture events to the Dismissible widget.

Comment: i want to read drag updates while swiping the item to dismiss.

Comment: So you are saying ```Dismissable``` is still not responding

Comment: Yes. The example u provided is for implementing two detectors and passing event to parent. In my case one is detector and other is Dismissible which internally implements detector, so how to achieve that.

Comment: It'll be very helpful if u can suggest me some ideas. Thnx

Comment: Okay funny enough I didn't have a problem getting ```Dismissible``` to respond but ```GestureDetector``` so I tried to define my own ```onHorizontalDragStart``` in ```RawGestureDetector``` which proved rather difficult. However I think I found a easier way check out updated code see if this works for you.

Comment: Right now ```onPointerMove``` works more like ```onHorizontalUpdate``` but with a Boolean you could fix that

Comment: Thnx, this is exactly what i want. It just need some tweaks.....

Answer (score 0):

If you use **InkWell** Instead of **Gesture Detector** with **Dismissible** problem will be solved