# Can you use onDismissed() and onTap() for the same list in flutter?

Tags: flutter, listview, dart

I have a list of items which I am displaying using `ListView.builder()` in flutter. I'd like to be able to use `onTap()` to navigate to another screen once an item has been tapped, but also swipe any item to delete it using `onDismissed()`. It seems I can only return to the builder either `ListTile` to use `onTap()` or `Dismissable` to use `onDismissed()`. Is there a way I can use both of these features on the same list?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use as top widget, a GestureDetector, then the Dismissible and finally your ListTile like this:

```
  return Scaffold(
  body: ListView.builder(
    itemCount: 10,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          print("Tap item index: $index");
        },
        child: Dismissible(
          onDismissed: (direction) {
            // remove item from list
          },
          background: Container(
            color: Colors.red,
          ),
          key: ObjectKey(index),
          child: ListTile(
            title: Text("Hello"),
          ),
        ),
      );
    },
  ),
);
```

Comment: this is not working. have you tried it?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61221813/gesturedetector-is-not-working-with-dismissible-widget

Answer (score 0):

you should try out this tecnique

```
return Container(
      child: movies.length > 0
          ? ListView.builder(
        itemCount: movies.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return InkWell(
            onTap: (){
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MovieDetails()),
              );
            },
            child: Dismissible(

              onDismissed: (DismissDirection direction) {
                setState(() {
                  movies.removeAt(index);
                });
              },
              secondaryBackground: Container(
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    'Delete',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ),
                color: Colors.red,
              ),
              background: Container(),
              child: MovieCard(movie: movies[index]),
              key: UniqueKey(),
              direction: DismissDirection.endToStart,
            ),
          );
        },
      )
          : Center(child: Text('No Items')),
    )
```